# ScrollTo() not scrolling in FireFox

Tags: atata

Here I am with another FireFox anomaly…

As I enter data on the page, the Save button scrolls out of view, so before clicking the Save button, I call Save.ScrollTo() – this works fine in Chrome and Edge, but FF does not scroll.  If I use ScrollUp(), FireFox does scroll up, so do you have some more magic so the scrollTo works in Firefox?

Here’s the trace log:

```
2021-09-01 16:57:30.7167 TRACE Scroll to "Save" button
2021-09-01 16:57:30.7183 TRACE - Execute behavior ScrollUsingMoveToElementAttribute against "Save" button
2021-09-01 16:57:30.7207 TRACE - - Find visible element by XPath ".//*[self::input[@type='button' or @type='submit' or @type='reset'] or self::button][normalize-space(.) = 'Save' or normalize-space(@value) = 'Save']" in FirefoxDriver
2021-09-01 16:57:31.0289  INFO Click "Save" button
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `[ScrollUsingScrollIntoView]` attribute to `Save` button. It will execute `element.scrollIntoView()` JavaScript to perform scrolling.

Comment: Still not working in FF:  2021-09-02 07:30:25.2630 TRACE Scroll to "Save" button
2021-09-02 07:30:25.2644 TRACE - Execute behavior ScrollUsingScrollIntoViewAttribute against "Save" button

Comment: And now Edge and Chrome stopped working, too.

Comment: I have a workaround - on the Save button:    [InvokeMethod(nameof(OnBeforeSave), TriggerEvents.BeforeClick)]    and the OnBeforeSave method checks to see if the Driver.Alias == firefox, and if so, ScrollUp()

Comment: Got it. If you are using `ScrollUp()` method, then you can also consider `[ScrollUp(TriggerEvents.BeforeClick)]` trigger usage. But it will execute regardless of browser.